# Monogame What's the new code for monogame for GraphicsDevice

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, vertex

I follow a tutorial, but I notice this problem:

```
GraphicsDevice.RenderState.CullMode = CullMode.None;

        GraphicsDevice.VertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration(GraphicsDevice, VertexPositionColor.VertexElements);
```

This code is missing in monogame, What should I do?
This is the complete code of the tutorial:

```
 protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        GraphicsDevice.RenderState.CullMode = CullMode.None;

        GraphicsDevice.VertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration(GraphicsDevice, VertexPositionColor.VertexElements);

        BasicEffect effect = new BasicEffect(GraphicsDevice, null);
        effect.World = Matrix.Identity;
        effect.View = camera.viewMatrix;
        effect.Projection = camera.projectionMatrix;

        effect.VertexColorEnabled = true;

        effect.Begin();
        foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Begin();
            GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, verts, 0, 2);
            pass.End();
        }
        effect.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to use a RasterizerState. RenderState was discontinued in XNA 4.0, I think.

`GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullNone;`

And look at this blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2010/04/19/vertex-data-in-xna-game-studio-4-0/

It covers changes to vertex declarations in XNA 4.0